# How to create a trigger based on a column value change from "S" to "D"

Tags: sql, informix

I have a scenario where I need a trigger to report whenever the column `src_system_id` on the table `purch_ord_hdr` gets changed from “S” to “D”.

The action must be triggered by `insert` or/and `update` based whenever the value changes. No matter if it is a `insert` or `update` statement.

Comment: First of all, if it is an insert it will not be getting changed from anything. Do you want the trigger to fire if new rows are created with a 'D' ?

Comment: That's nice. Did you have a question or just sharing the business rules of a project you have? We will be happy to help you but most people around here are not willing to do your work for you. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Informix?

Comment: Which one is it? Microsoft SQL Server or Informix. The answers will be **very** different

Comment: This is for Informix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tell which version of IDS you're running.

Nonetheless, check this test case and adapt.

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(
    col1            CHAR(1) 
);

CREATE TABLE tab1_hist(
        col1_old        CHAR(1),
        col1_new        CHAR(1),
        user            VARCHAR(32),
        event           CHAR(1),
        date            DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND
);


CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ti_tab1(val CHAR(1))
        INSERT INTO tab1_hist (col1_new, user, event, date)
                VALUES (val, USER, 'I', CURRENT);
END PROCEDURE;

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_tu_tab1(val_o CHAR(1), val_n CHAR(1))
        INSERT INTO tab1_hist (col1_old, col1_new, user, event, date)
                VALUES (val_o, val_n, USER, 'U', CURRENT);
END PROCEDURE;

CREATE TRIGGER ti_tab1
        INSERT OF col1 ON tab1
        REFERENCING NEW AS new
        FOR EACH ROW WHEN(new.col1 = 'D')
                (EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_ti_tab1(new.col1));

CREATE TRIGGER tu_tab1
        UPDATE OF col1 ON tab1
        REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old
        FOR EACH ROW WHEN(new.col1 = 'D' AND old.col1 = 'A')
                (EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_tu_tab1(old.col1, new.col1));
```

Comment: I forgot to include the version, however I am running off IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC4W1WE AIX server

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, Try this (modified to include your table name and Primary Key column name)

```
create trigger on [Table name here]
for insert, update 
as
Set NoCount On
    if Exists
      ( Select * From inserted I 
           left join deleted d 
               on d.PKCol = i.PKCol  -- < replace PKCol w/name of Prim Key
        Where i.src_system_id = 'D' 
            and isnull(d.src_system_id, 'S') = 'S')
     Begin
         -- Here put code to do whatever you want trigger to do
     End
```

Comment: How much would this differ to Informix

Comment: Can you detect which user is changing the value from S to D

Comment: I don't know Informix